# Where did I go wrong with this Boolean simplification?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am completely new to Boolean algebra, and I've tried to simplify this expression. All I did is tried to follow my lecturers methods, but I don't think it's right, and I have no idea how to do it.

¬a∧¬b∧¬c ∨ a∧¬b∧c ∨ a∧b∧¬c ∨ a∧b∧c

First, I picked out the "¬b"-s from the first two expressions, based on the distributive law:

¬b (¬a∧¬c ∨ a∧c) ∨ a∧b∧¬c ∨ a∧b∧c

Next, I picked up the "a"-s from the last two expressions based on the distributive law:

¬b (¬a∧¬c ∨ a∧c) ∨ a (b∧¬c ∨ b∧c)

Then, I thought I could cancel out "(¬a∧¬c ∨ a∧c)" completely, since they are opposite of each other (hope I'm right):

¬b ∨ a (b∧¬c ∨ b∧c)

Then again, I applied the distributive law to "pick out" the "b"-s:

¬b ∨ a (b (¬c∧c))

Next, I cancelled out "(¬c∧c)":

¬b ∨ a∧b

Then, applying negative absorption, I have removed "¬b", leading to:

a∧b

I am pretty sure I can't simplify this to a single AND gate, it is impossible for the truth tables to be the same, but I don't have a clue about the whole thing. Where did I misunderstand the applied rules, and what is the correct solution?
(The work is really urgent and I appreciate your help very much. After this I won't even learn Boolean algebra - I am trying to be a sysadmin, not a hardware engineer :) )

Comment: One issue that makes your proof hard to follows is the fact that $x\vee y \wedge z$ is ambiguous.  You can mean $x\vee (y\wedge z)$ or $(x\vee y)\wedge z$.

Comment: Sorry about that... the expression I was trying to simplify is:
(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧¬b∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧b∧c)
Then I picked out "¬b" from the first 2 parts:
¬b (¬a∧¬c ∨ a∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧b∧c)
Then I picked out "a" from the last 2 parts:
¬b (¬a∧¬c ∨ a∧c) ∨ a (b∧¬c ∨ b∧c)
And I'm stuck here (my next step is wrong according to the first answer).

Answer (score 1):

After third step, you cannot cancel (¬a∧¬c ∨ a∧c). You can cancel ¬(a∧c) ∨ a∧c but this is not the case. Remember also to respect the operators order: $$a ∧ b ∨ c$$ means $$( a ∧ b ) ∨ c$$

p.s. in my opinion, evereone(engineer, sys admins, lawers ...) must learn boolean algebra :) .

Comment: I see, thanks.
Well, I'd like to understand it better too :D Can I simplify it further after the first two steps, or do I need a different start in the first place? (and what would be the best exactly?)

I'll post my next attempt in a bit

Comment: Here's my next try... I have removed the "¬a∧¬c" and the "¬c" according to negative absorption:

¬b (a∧c) ∨ a (b ∨ b∧c)

Am I correct or why not - and can I simplify it further?

Comment: A goog resource for compuiting boolean expression. Here you can find the solution for your particular problem. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not+A+and+not+B+and+not+C+or+A+and+not+B+and+C+or+A+and+B+and+not+C+or+A+and+B+and+C

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you cannot simplify $a\wedge c\vee\neg a\wedge\neg c$ as $1.$  Let's consider an expression of the form $$(d\wedge e)\vee(\neg d\wedge\neg e).$$ By distributivity, we have $$\bigl((d\wedge e)\vee\neg d\bigr)\wedge\bigl((d\wedge e)\vee\neg e\bigr),$$ and applying distributivity again gives us $$\bigl((d\vee\neg d)\wedge (e\vee\neg d)\bigr)\wedge\bigl((d\vee\neg e)\wedge (e\vee\neg e)\bigr),$$ which we can simplify to $$(e\vee\neg d)\wedge(d\vee\neg e).$$ That really isn't much simpler, so it isn't necessarily worth the effort.

You *can* simplify $a\wedge b\wedge\neg c\vee a\wedge b\wedge c$ as $a\wedge b,$ though, just as you did. Here's a bit of a slick trick (called idempotence) you can use: $p\vee p$ is the same as $p.$ What we can do, then, is note that the following are equivalent (parentheses inserted for a bit more clarity): $$(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧¬b∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧b∧c)\\(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧¬b∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧b∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧c)\\(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧¬b∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧b∧c)\\(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧¬b∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧c) ∨ \bigl(a∧b∧(¬c∨c)\bigr)\\(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧¬b∧c) ∨ (a∧b∧c) ∨ (a∧b)\\(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ \bigl(a∧(¬b ∨ b)∧c\bigr) ∨ (a∧b)\\(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ (a∧c) ∨ (a∧b)\\(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ \bigl(a∧(c ∨ b)\bigr)\\(¬a∧¬b∧¬c) ∨ \bigl(a∧(b ∨ c)\bigr)\\\bigl(a∧(b ∨ c)\bigr) ∨ (¬a∧¬b∧¬c)$$

All of that just used idempotence, inverse, distributivity, identity, and commutativity properties. This is pretty much as simple as it gets. At this point, we *could* use DeMorgan's laws to write $\neg b\wedge\neg c$ as $\neg(b\vee c).$ So, our expression becomes $$\bigl(a∧(b ∨ c)\bigr) ∨ \bigl(¬a∧¬(b\vee c)\bigr)$$ But this is just another expression of the form $(d\wedge e)\vee(\neg d\wedge\neg e),$ and as we saw above, there isn't much we can do with that if $d$ and $e$ are logically independent (as I assume that $a,b\vee c$ ought to be).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cameron Buie.

Let's consider an expression of the form
(d∧e)∨(¬d∧¬e).

By distributivity, we have

((d∧e)∨¬d)∧((d∧e)∨¬e),

and applying distributivity again gives us

((d∨¬d)∧(e∨¬d))∧((d∨¬e)∧(e∨¬e)),

which we can simplify to

(e∨¬d)∧(d∨¬e).